# ImportError: cannot import name 'preprocess_input' from 'tensorflow.keras.preprocessing'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm working on google colab , and I want to import **preprocess_input** from **tensorflow.keras.preprocessing** but this error keeps occurring , while whatever I import from tensorflow work fine except this .

well i'm using **tensorflow = 2.8.0**

my code :

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import preprocess_input
```

the error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-2569fd104ea5> in <module>()
----> 1 from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import preprocess_input

ImportError: cannot import name 'preprocess_input' from 'tensorflow.keras.preprocessing' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/api/_v2/keras/preprocessing/__init__.py)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

what should I install or change to fix this error , i just want to use **preprocess_input** for model predicting purposes that's all , any suggestions please !

Comment: Hello Nacereddine, `tf.keras.preprocessing` is deprecated. Can you please try to use `tf.keras.applications.resnet50.preprocess_input` or `tf.keras.applications.imagenet_utils.preprocess_input` as per your requirement. Thanks!